# JUnit Testing. Type mismatch: cannot convert from Store to List<Store>

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, junit

I think I miss the syntax at "thenReturn" part. What should I wrote for the source code?

[image]

here's the source code:

```
@Test
public void testGetUserByEmail() {
    String email = "mail";
    when(storeService.search(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Mockito.any(Store.class));
    ModelAndView mav = storeController.search(email);
    Assert.assertEquals("userDetail", mav.getViewName());
}
```

here's the service:

```
public List<Store> listAllStore(){
    logger.info("Before add repository to show all");
    List<Store> all_stores=(List<Store>) storeRepo.findAll();
    logger.info("After add repository to show all");
    logger.info(all_stores);
    return all_stores;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Few observations

1. `when(storeService.search(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Mockito.any(Store.class));` theReturn should provide some actual data when storeService.search() is called. It should be something like `when(storeService.search(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(testData);` where testData is of type storeService.search() returns.
2. In your test case, you are mocking `storeService.search()` but in your example, you have provided definition of `listAllStore`. Which one is correct? Either you need to fix your question or test case.